# Connect4 Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been given an assignment to build a connect4 game using java in eclipse, I was given most of the classes and methods involved to build it, but I am having a problem understanding the static main void part. I have always had some problems understanding how to initialize things in it. Below are all the classes involved.Any help would be great

```
/**
 * This class represents a board for Connect 4. Please method headers as is.
 * 
 * @author
 * 
 */

public class Board {

    private LocationState board[][];
    private int noCols, noRows;

    /**
     * 
     * This constructor creates and initialises the board.
     * 
     * @param col   the number of columns in the board
     * @param row   the number of rows in the board
     * @see LocationState
     */
    public Board(int col, int row) {

        board = new LocationState[col][row];
        noCols = col;
        noRows = row;
        clear();

    }

    /**
     * This method clears the board by setting each element to
     * LocationState.EMPTY
     * 
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public void clear() {

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
                board[i][j] = LocationState.EMPTY;

    }
    /**
     * This method gets the location state (i.e. colour) at a particular
     * location
     * 
     * @param location
     * @return Location state as LocationState
     * @see Location
     * @see LocationState
     */
    public LocationState getLocationState(Location location) {
        return board[location.getX()][location.getY()];
    }

    /**
     * This method sets the location state (i.e. colour) at a particular
     * location
     * 
     * @param location
     * @return Nothing
     * @see Location
     * @see LocationState
     */
    public boolean setLocationState(Location location, LocationState state) {
        if (location.getX() < getNoCols() && location.getY() < getNoRows()) {
            board[location.getX()][location.getY()] = state;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < noRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < noCols; j++)
                s += (board[j][i] + "\t");
            s += "\n";
        }

        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of columns on the board.
     * 
     * @return number of columns on board as an integer
     */
    public int getNoCols() {
        return noCols;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of rows on the board.
     * 
     * @return number of rows on board as an integer
     */
    public int getNoRows() {
        return noRows;
    }

}

/**
 * 
 * Example Computer Player.
 * CREATE YOUR OWN VERSION OF THIS, REPLACING THE NUMBER IN THE CLASS NAME 
 * WITH YOUR STUDENT NUMBER.
 * @author Frank
 *
 */
public class ComputerPlayer20059226 extends IPlayer {

    public ComputerPlayer20059226(LocationState playerState) {
        super(playerState);

    }

    @Override
    public int getMove(Board board) {

        //TODO
        return -1;

    }
}



/**
 * 
 * Class to manage the connect 5 game
 *
 */
public class Connect4 {

    private IPlayer human, computer;
    private Board board;
    private IPlayer currentPlayer;
    private int numTurns = 0;

    public Connect4(IPlayer human, IPlayer computer, Board board) {
        super();
        this.human = human;
        this.computer = computer;
        this.board = board;
        this.currentPlayer = human;

    }


    /**
     * Toggles current player 
     */
    public void nextPlayer() {

        if (currentPlayer == human) {
            currentPlayer = computer;

        } else {
            currentPlayer = human;

        }

    }

    /**
     * Checks if there's a winner
     * @param board to evaluate for winner 
     * @return boolean to detect winner
     */
    public boolean isWin(Board board) {

        //TODO
        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Checks for a draw
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isDraw() {
        if(numTurns == board.getNoCols() * board.getNoRows())
        {
            return true;

        }
        else return false;

    }

    /**
     * Method called to get next move from player
     * 
     * @return boolean indicating move take successfully
     */
    public boolean takeTurn() {

        int col = currentPlayer.getMove(board);

        for (int i = 0; i < board.getNoRows(); i++) {
            if (board.getLocationState(new Location(col, i)) == LocationState.EMPTY) {
                board.setLocationState(new Location(col, i),
                        currentPlayer.getPlayerState());
                numTurns++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connect4 connect = new Connect4(human.YELLOW);
    }

}


**
 * 
 * Abstract class to represent a player in a Connect 4 game.
 * Extend this to create your player.
 * Dependent on LocationState and Board types
 * @author Frank
 *
 */
public abstract class IPlayer {

    private LocationState playerState;

    public IPlayer(LocationState playerState) {
        super();
        this.playerState = playerState;
    }



    /**
     * This method should return the next move for a Connect 4 game.
     * Assume columns go from 1 to 7. Move computed from board parameter 
     * using suitable algorithm.
     * @param board - Connect 4 board as type Board
     * @return column number for next turn as integer.
     */
    public abstract int getMove(Board board);





    /**
     * This method returns the location state (i.e. colour) associated
     * with the player.
     * @return playerState - colour of players piece as LocationState.
     */
    public LocationState getPlayerState() {
        return playerState;
    }




}



public class Location {

    private int x;
    private int y;




    public Location(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

}

/**
 * Emum class to represent possible location states in a connect 4 board  
 * @author Frank
 *
 */
public enum LocationState {
    EMPTY, RED, YELLOW;
}
```

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about what exactly you are having difficulty with. We're not just going to read through that entire codebase and explain it all to you.

Comment: Did you acually read the code / the assignment? You are supposed to implement `IPlayer` with your student number.

Comment: I don't want the code to be explained to me? I already know what it does. The problem I am having is in how I initialize the Connect4 class in the static void. Do I just do Connect4 connect = new Connect4()<-- I'm not sure what to put in here. That's my problem.

Comment: The code creates a board and two players human and computer, the game rotates turns allow the player and the computer to go, after each turn the code checks if the  player or computer has won, it then checks if a draw has taken place. The player and computer are given colors through the LocationState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main method should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IPlayer human = new HumanPlayer(); // <-- you have to create this class (assignment)
    IPlayer computer = new ComputerPlayer20059226();
    Board board = new Board(16, 16);
    Connect4 connect = new Connect4(human, computer, board);
    // do something with the objects        
}
```

It seems that your assignment is mainly to create a concrete version of `IPlayer` representing yourself:

```
public class HumanPlayer extends IPlayer {
    ...
}
```

The name of the class `IPlayer` in your assignment should actually be `AbstractPlayer`, since `IPlayer` suggests that it is an interface, not an abstract class.

```
public abstract class IPlayer { // <-- bad naming
```

Furthermore you are also asked to implement the method `public boolean isWin(Board board)` in the class `Connect4`.

Even though that should not be dificult I think the fact that the method has a parameter of type `Board` and at the same time is *not* static is really misleading, since the instance of `Connect4` already has an instance of a `Board` as member.

Comment: Do I have to make two new classes for the human and computer or can I implement them into the Connect4 class.

Comment: The computer class already exists. You have to create a new class for the human player. Use a new File called like the class for this.